Sentinel-2 shadow postprocessing issues
I was looking at some recent Sentinel-2 L2A true colour (bands 4,3,2) images of the Scottish highlands on the Copernicus browser, and noticed that in the presence of snow cover the shadows cast by topography have been postprocessed somehow, into a shade of light blue as opposed to appearing darker. Here's an example at the point where this effect started (further south where there is no snow, all shadows appear darker as expected). Could anyone explain what is happening to cause this?

